# Troubleshooting clipping

Tags: electrical-engineering, signal-processing, acoustics, audio-engineering

I am collecting data for a project, where I am measuring the room impulse response by playing a sine sweep from a speaker (QSC K8 1KW Active Loudspeaker) and measuring it from the other side of the room using a microphone array.
Even though the sine sweep is very clean (bottom image), there appear to be these "ghost sweeps" in the recordings from the microphone.

[image: Clipping Example in Spectrogram]

[image: Original Sine Sweep]

If I look at the recording in Audacity it is not clipping. I tried using other microphone systems and have concluded that the clipping must be occurring while the sound is playing, or before that in the signal chain. I have tried playing the sound in different ways (from Audacity, from Python) and the clipping is still occurring. So, I have concluded that the clipping must be occurring somewhere in one of these steps:

1. When the signal is sent to the audio interface (MOTU 8M)
2. When the audio interface is sending the signal to the speaker
3. When the speaker is playing the audio.
4. Power source to the speaker?

I have tried using a different speaker (an ADAM studio monitor) still with clipping occurring.
The signal is being sent to the speaker via

1. A TRS to XLR cable
2. and XLR to XLR cable.

and I have tried replacing cable 2 (I do not have a replacement for cable 1).

I have also tried lowering the volume of the signal sent to the speaker. This alleviates the artifacts, but even at very low volumes there are still some ghost sweeps! I get a bad signal-to-noise at such volumes.

I have read something about "impedance matching" but I don't really understand. I have seen [Audio frequency sweep spectrogram artifacts... hints?](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16101/audio-frequency-sweep-spectrogram-artifacts-hints) but there does not appear to be an answer.

Raw Waveform:

[image]

Comment: Test the equipment: both generator and receiver, in an anechoic chamber to be sure it behaves as designed. Then you can evaluate the room.

Comment: @SolarMike The room is already as anechoic as we can get it (lots of acoustic treatment).

Comment: Are the ghosts, **harmonics** of the tone being played ? Can you share a plot of the waveform transmitted and received ? Perhaps from 6.0s to 6.1s ? Even better: share the digital data (say from 6.0s to 6.5s) ? Clipping is not the only **non linear** phenomena which can generate **harmonics**.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DluJdTk3v8CkHFm9P-cqXwTWgVLDWwgB?usp=sharing

Comment: I shared a link above to the clipped wav file, and a .npy file of the audio data from 6.0 6.5 seconds. Thanks for your help, let me know if I can provide it in a different format. I added a picture of the raw waveform to the post.

Comment: Best guess is it is coming from the speaker's crossover network.

Comment: It appears to be specific to the algorithm used by Audacity. I cant get this result using GNU Octave *fft* function. (assuming that `testsweepsm573.wav` in the shared folder corresponds to the **microphone** data).

Comment: What is the *colour scale* used by Audacity?

Comment: I suggest you play a constant tone of 1000 Hz, plot the spectrum of that. The answer below suggest it is 2nd order harmonic at -40dB,  second order is NOT simple clipping, which is 3,5,7 etc. I vaguely remember 2nd order is diode like behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The data provide by OP in the file `testsweepsm573.wav` is fed to GNU Octave. A slice of data taken at 6s is fed to the `fft` function. The result shows a pure sinusoid. The image is attached below.

[image: signal and its spectrum]

We can notice the second harmonic at 6000Hz when the spectrum is plotted in logscale (dB). Perhaps *Audacity* is using log scale to render the image.

So the *ghost* does exist, but appears to be of really small magnitude.

Comment: Audacity [Settings](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/spectrogram_settings.html), [Spectrogram](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/spectrogram_view.html), [Preferences](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/spectrograms_preferences.html).

Comment: This is **absolutely normal** and corresponds to the first order harmonic distortion product. The appearance of such products is normal and a fortunate and welcomed "byproduct" of the method

Comment: -40 dB first harmonic, it'd be interestng to see wht the higher harmonics are at say around t=4. How many bits is the DA converter?